# perl how to get filename and extension

Tags: perl

I have an input file called test1.txt with hundreds & thousands of file names.

```
test word document.docx
...
...
amazing c. document.docx
1. 2. 3.45 document.docx
...
...
```

What I want to do is get filename and extension out of the string. For majority of the file names there is only one dot so I am able to get filename and ext using dot as a separator. But the problem is that some file names have multiple dots in the filenames. I have no idea how I would get the extention and file name out of that.

Here's my perl code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Perl Starting ... \n\n"; 

open my $input_filehandle1, , '<', 'test1.txt' or die "No input Filename Found test1.txt ... \n";

while (defined(my $recordLine = <$input_filehandle1>))
{
    chomp($recordLine);

    my @fields = split(/\./, $recordLine);
    my $arrayCount = @fields;


    #if the array size is more than 2 then we encountered multiple dots
    if ($arrayCount > 2)
    {
        print "I dont know how to get filename and ext ... $recordLine ... \n";
    }
    else
    {   
        print "FileName: $fields[0] ... Ext: $fields[1] ... \n";
    }

}#end while-loop

print "\nPerl End ... \n\n"; 

1;
```

Here's the output:

```
Perl Starting ...

FileName: test word document ... Ext: docx ...
I dont know how to get filename and ext ... amazing c. document.docx ...
I dont know how to get filename and ext ... 1. 2. 3.45 document.docx ...

Perl End ...
```

What I would like to get

```
FileName: test word document ... Ext: docx ...
FileName: amazing c. document ... Ext: docx ...
FileName: 1. 2. 3.45 document ... Ext: docx ...
```

Comment: Use REGEX : https://regex101.com/r/L9fLGX/1

Comment: [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) is handy.

Comment: @PhxDev that was wonderful! Thank you. The only question I have is that regex makes 3 items in array per line instead of two. The first value in array is always blank. Not sure why but it works. Let me post a solution

Comment: The first element in the array is `$0` for all the line. And `$1` for the filemane and `$2` for the extension. 
Please mark my answer as usefull ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `split`.

Use just a regular pattern match:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Perl Starting ... \n\n"; 

open my $input_filehandle1, , '<', 'test1.txt' or die "No input Filename Found test1.txt ... \n";

while (defined(my $recordLine = <$input_filehandle1>))
{
    chomp($recordLine);

    if ($recordLine =~ /^(.*)\.([^.]+)$/) {
      print "FileName: $1 ... Ext: $2 ... \n";
    }

}#end while-loop

print "\nPerl End ... \n\n"; 

1;
```

Regexper explains the [regular expression](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28.*%29%5C.%28%5B%5E.%5D%2B%29%24).

Comment: This all gets lot neater if you use `$_` instead of `$recordLine` :-)

Comment: This is the regex I ended up using  /(.*)\.(\w+)$/

Comment: @DaveCross Of course, but this is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This is what [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) is for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use File::Basename;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($name, undef, $ext) = fileparse($_, '.docx');

  say "Filename: $name ... Ext: $ext";
}

__DATA__
test word document.docx
amazing c. document.docx
1. 2. 3.45 document.docx
```

Three things that are worth explaining.

1. I use the `DATA` filehandle as this is a demonstration and it's easier than having a separate input file.
2. `fileparse()` returns the directory path as the second value. As this data doesn't include directory paths, I've ignored that value (by assigning it to `undef`).
3. The second (and subsequent) parameters to `fileparse()` are a list of extensions to separate out. You only use one extension in your sample data. If you had more extensions, you could just add them after ".docx".

Comment: Dave, this is a good answer. It works great as long as I know what the file ext is. If I encounter an ext that I didn't add then the fileparse won't work.